# prompt number that scrolls with loop using if and else

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to insert a number in a prompt and scroll the screen using a for loop with if and else statements, and not success. The code behaves in way that when the loop iterates, the alert seems to pop in the process, and not as a result in the end "a pop up" saying there is no such number in the database to reach for, or the final result if there is the right number according to what was in the range(of numbers possible into entry) and without the pop up iterating, neither a pop up popping at least once when not wanted. The way I want the code to behave is, if there is no matching number then the alert should pop up. I would accept even a `array` in exchange of a better answer to the code I mentioned bellow, so that I am not restricted to a few tools(sort of say) and everything is welcome for the learning purpose. Though if there is a better solution but can be done with/without the tools I mentioned, I would pick the few tools(codes) I mentioned and it is what the preferable answer and just in case there is solution with it(the few codes I mentioned) or in case if not, I'm open to more tools available.

This is not even my best shot:

```
function off() {
    var ik = prompt("type a number from 1 to 1000");
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
        if(ik == i){
            window.scrollTo(1366*i, 0);
            break;
        } else {
             alert("");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: do you have a page with that length?

Comment: Why do you need the loop, if you only`window.scroll` in the single case `ik == i`? As far as I see, your code does the same as `for (var i = 0; i<ik;i++) { alert(""); } window.scroll(...);` Why not using a scrolling-animation?

Comment: If user enters '999' the page is going to try and scroll 1,364,634 pixels - that's a really long page!  Why even bother with the for-loop?

Comment: Yes I have a with page with that length, planning to get even larger. A page animation would break my ideal goal, if there is scroll bar under the browser where the user can navigate.
https://story.000webhostapp.com

Comment: I need the scroll just in divided areas(the multiplication sign is what makes divisions between place to place), 1366*1,then 1366*2 and so forth. 0 is where the else statements say no or any number that's not in the range possible.

Comment: If 1,364,634 pixels is long, imagine if I put that in if/else if/else script file size which I did and worked. A shortcut cut for loop in script would save me a lot of data size.

Comment: Wouldn't a slider/carousel be a better way of going about it?

Comment: I think is good thing to bring up, although cross browser in at first is compromised. A slider/carousel can be a further option to the user for mobile and other kind of devices whereas that can be good, but not what I intend here at the moment. Thank you, for coming up with one of further alternatives.

Comment: @JobsonModesto, are you satisfied with the comments so far? Otherwise, please include some details in your post a) how your code does actually behave and b) how it should behave.